# Using AngularJS to connect to Splunk's REST API, how do I resolve CORS issue?

Tags: angularjs, cors, splunk

When I try to post data from AngularJS, I am getting the below error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:8089/services/auth/login.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Here is the angularjs code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
sessionkey='';
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://localhost:8089/services/auth/login',
    headers : {
      'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept':'*/*'

    },
    data : {
      username : 'admin',
      password : 'admin',
      output_mode : 'json' 
    }
};



app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
$http(req).success(function($scope, $http){
    sessionKey= retrieveSessionKey($scope, $http);

});

});
```

How can I get around the issue?

Appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1):

From [Splunk dev site](http://dev.splunk.com/view/webframework-splunkjsstack/SP-CAAAEW6):

> Web apps that run outside of Splunk Web need to use a proxy server or cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) to communicate with the Splunk server due to Same Origin Policy (SOP) browser security policies.
>
> If you are using CORS, you'll need to configure the Splunk server to allow your web site to communicate with it using a CORS connection. To do this, add your web site's address as a trusted HTTP origin to the crossOriginSharingPolicy attribute in the server.conf configuration file.

For example, add this stanza to the `$SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/server.conf` configuration file, then restart Splunk:

```
[httpServer]
crossOriginSharingPolicy = your_site_address
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving a note for other people who still have CORS problems even after setting the server.conf:

I also set up **server.conf, web.conf, and inputs.conf** in the $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/*.conf, and added the following:

Under server.conf add the following lines

```
[httpServer] 
crossOriginSharingPolicy = *
```

Under web.conf add the following lines

```
[settings]
crossOriginSharingPolicy = *
```

Under inputs.conf add the following lines

```
[http]
crossOriginSharingPolicy = *
```

I found this info from the [splunk answer page](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/766107/how-do-i-send-data-to-http-event-collector-via-jav.html)

After the set up, everything started to work.